# MySQL: joining 2 tables and display the last date of the child table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to display a list of customers, with their total purchase count and total amount spent, and additionally, I need a column with the date of their LAST purchase.

This is my current query, but it doesn't display the last available date of the last purchase:

```
SELECT user.id_user AS id,
purchase.date_insert AS last_purchase,
CONCAT(user.lastname, " ", user.name) AS name,
COUNT(purchase.id_purchase) AS purchases,
SUM(purchase.total) AS total
FROM user
JOIN purchase ON purchase.id_user = user.id_user
GROUP BY user.id_user
ORDER BY name
```

Instead of just using `purchase.date_insert AS last_purchase` (which is retrieving the first available value of that column) I need to get the LAST available value for that column.

Here's a sqlfiddle of the structure and some data sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d83684/1

As you can see in the example, the `last_purchase` column is displaying **2019-03-26T09:38:40Z**, and it should be **2019-04-01 12:01:24Z**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must want `max()`:

```
SELECT u.id_user AS id,
       MAX(p.date_insert) AS last_purchase,
       CONCAT(u.lastname, ' ', user.name) AS name,
       COUNT(p.id_purchase) AS purchases,
       SUM(p.total) AS total
FROM user u JOIN
     purchase p
     ON p.id_user = u.id_user
GROUP BY u.id_user
ORDER BY MAX(u.name);
```

In most databases -- including the more recent versions of MySQL with the default settings -- your query would return an error.  You have columns in the `SELECT` and the `ORDER BY` that are not aggregation keys and that are not aggregated.

Comment: That worked, I'm a little lost at the end of your comment though. Should I re-structure my keys so that they are aggregation keys ?

Comment: @AndresSK . . . This answer address the issue.  Note the difference in the `ORDER BY` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

just use max()

```
SELECT user.id_user AS id,
max(purchase.date_insert) AS last_purchase,
CONCAT(user.lastname, " ", user.name) AS name,
COUNT(purchase.id_purchase) AS purchases,
SUM(purchase.total) AS total
FROM user
JOIN purchase ON purchase.id_user = user.id_user
GROUP BY user.id_user,user.lastname,user.name
ORDER BY name
```

and i prefer to use group by non aggregated columns in group by thoguh mysql is not return error if not used those in group by